# Function call inside a loop python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension

I do have following problem -

```
dict1 = {'abc': {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 4}, 'mno': {'p': 3, 'q':4, 'r':5}} 

def refine():
    def calc(a_dict):
        if some_condition :
           return x ={'a':1}
        else:
           return None

    for k, v in dict1:
        return calc(v)
```

Now when I am `iterating` this function call inside a for loop , I get either `None` or `a`. The function call is such that I can get maximum of one `a` .

**Sample Output**-

```
None
None
{'a':1}
None
```

What I want `calc` function to return `None` in case all the values after the loop gives `None` or `x` in case any of the values after loop gives `x` .How can this be achieved ? Thanks in advance.

**Edit** -
What if I store the results in a list and want to check if the list has something else than `None` and `if True` return it.

Comment: what is the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I did get the question, you may store results of conditions applied on a dictionary and then check with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) quantifier function:

```
def calc(a_dict):
    results = (some_condition(k,v) for k,v in a_dict.iteritems())
    if all(res == None for res in results):
        return None
    elif all(res == <something> for res in results):
        return {'a':1}
    else:
        return <something different>
```

Comment: What if I want to store it in a list ?

Comment: @AyushTiwari Do you mean results of `calc` function ? Quite easily like `[calc(v) for v in dict1.itervalues()]` .

Answer (score 0):

u can use any() . any check for the condition if any one value is true. it return x . if all values fail it goes to else

```
if any(somecondition):
    return x
else:
    return None
```

Comment: What if I store the results in a list and want to check if the list has something else than `None` and `if True` return it.